# Why does the generated view binding .inflate() method requires root parameter?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding, android-viewbinding

I was following the example from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) on a personal project.

I have a layout called `activity_main.xml`, for which an `ActivityMainBinding` class is generated. When I call `ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)`, I get an error saying that the method requires the "root" parameter of type `ViewGroup`.

Why isn't the method with only one argument (the inflater) available?

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project.

**build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.teddy"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/navdrawer" />
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</merge>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.teddy

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.example.teddy.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout

        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, drawerLayout)
        findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.navView)
            .setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

**EDIT**
The exact error from the failed build output:

> No value passed for parameter 'parent’

The tooltip on the underlined error in the code says

> No value passed for parameter 'root'

Comment: Can you post the exact error message and stacktrace.

Answer (score 4):

I might have solved the problem by changing the merge tag by a layout tag in the activity_main.xml. Not really sure why I had a merge there... Probably legacy of a template.

Thank you for looking into it !

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `setContentView` method in `DataBindingUtil`.

Change this

```
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
```

to this

```
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
```

Comment: Why is this method preferred?

I get another error saying:

Type parameter bound for T in fun <T : ViewDataBinding!> setContentView(p0: Activity, p1: Int): T!
 is not satisfied: inferred type ActivityMainBinding! is not a subtype of ViewDataBinding!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem. In my case, substituting merge with layout in activity_main.xml gave me an error.
Instead, I solved using

```
FrameLayout
```